# How to develop an optimal parser scheme?

Tags: c#

I wrote a parser using AngleSharp.
Site for parsing taken conditionally for the test.

Code

```
 public async void Parser()
        {
            // *** HtmlLoader ***
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string currentUrl = "https://github.com/search?q=winform&type=Repositories";
            var response = await client.GetAsync(currentUrl);
             string source = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // результат парсинга 


            // HTML парсер, который доступен из "AngleSharp".
            var domParser = new HtmlParser();

            // Спарсим асинхронно наш исходный код и получим документ с которым мы можем работать
            var document = await domParser.ParseAsync(source);


            // *** Парсинг ***
            // var items = document.QuerySelectorAll("a").Where(item =>
            //         item.ClassName != null && item.ClassName.Contains("post__title_link"));

            var fieldNameCollect = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.col-12.col-md-8.pr-md-3 > h3");
            var fieldDescriptCollect = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.col-12.col-md-8.pr-md-3 > p");            
            var fieldUpdateCollect = document.QuerySelectorAll("div > p > relative-time");            
            var fieldLangCollect = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.text-gray.flex-auto.min-width-0"); 
            var fieldStarCollect = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.pl-2.pl-md-0.text-right.flex-auto.min-width-0 > a");


            // Колличество
            int count = fieldNameCollect.Length;

            // Перебор элементов
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                string fieldName = fieldNameCollect[i].TextContent;
                string fieldDescript = fieldDescriptCollect[i].TextContent;                
                string fieldUpdate = fieldUpdateCollect[i].TextContent;
                string fieldLang =  fieldLangCollect[i].TextContent;
                string fieldStar = fieldStarCollect[i].TextContent;

                ConnectDBAccess connectDBAccess = new ConnectDBAccess(tableName, pathDB);

                connectDBAccess.InsertRecord(fieldName, fieldDescript, fieldUpdate, fieldLang, fieldStar);
            }
```

The principle of the parser:
- the parser gets a collection of each field;
- the parser performs collection of the collection by index;
- the parser enters the data in the database;

Questions
1. Does such a parser scheme have disadvantages and how to make it more optimal?

Comment: Please define `optimal` and also `more correctly`. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: @PeterB  Corrected the issue `Does such a parser scheme have disadvantages and how to make it more optimal?`  Would that be right?

Comment: This code is working, so it looks for me like an opinion-based question, which is also more related to software engineering than stackoverflow.

Comment: This may be better asked @ https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic - If ConnectDBAccess() opens a connection to a database then that's something you definitely do not want to do in a loop, its expensive.  Open outside the loop then close after the loop.